# If$ f_x(x)$ is a continuous PDF with symmetry$ f_x(a) = f_x(-a)$ for any $a > 0$. Show $P(-a \leq X \leq a)$ = ....

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose that $f_X(x)$ is a continuous PDF with the symmetry property that $f_X(a) = f_X(−a)$ for any $a > 0$. Show that $P(−a \leq X \leq a) = 2F_X(a)−1$ where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF corresponding to the PDF $f_X(x)$.

Comment: So here's what I'm thinking; P(-a <= X <= a) = the integral from -a to 0 of f_X(x) + the integral from 0 to a of f_X(x).

Comment: Somehow this simplifies to 2F_X(a) - 1

Answer (score 0):

$$P(-a \leq X \leq 0) = \int_{-a}^0 f_X(s) \, ds$$

Let $t = -s$, we have

$$\int_{-a}^0 f_X(s) \, ds = \int_{a}^0 f_X(-t) \, \times (-1)dt = \int_{0}^a f_X(-t) \, dt = \int_{0}^a f_X(t) \, dt$$

Hence we have

$$P(-a \leq X \leq a) = 2 \int_{0}^a f_X(s) \, ds = 2(F_X(a) - F_X(0))$$

On the other hand, since

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(s) \, ds = \int_{0}^{-\infty} f_X(-t) \, \times (-1)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f_X(t) \, dt $$
$$ 1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(s) \, ds = 2 \int_{-\infty}^{0} f_X(s) \, ds = 2F_X(0)$$

Therefore we have

$$P(-a \leq X \leq a) = 2 \int_{0}^a f_X(s) \, ds = 2F_X(a) - 1$$